Showing why Poisson random variable is not sub gaussian
I looked at a previous answer posted on stackexchange; Poisson random variable is not sub gaussian; however, I cannot see how to obtain a lower-bound using Stirling's approximation.
For context, I am trying to show that the Poisson distribution is not sub-guassian, by hopefully showing that the the upper tail decays strictly slower than $\exp(-ct^{2})$. The approach notes that, for $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, we have that
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X| \geq t) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq t) > \mathbb{P}(X = t) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{t}}{t!}
$$
We know, by Stirling's approximation, that $t! \sim \sqrt{2\pi t}\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)^{t}$.  So, we have that
$$
\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{t}}{t!} \sim \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{t}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)^{t}} \sim \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{t}}{t^{1/2}\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)^{t}} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{t^{1/2}} \cdot \left(\frac{\lambda e}{t}\right)^{t}
$$
which, to me, goes to $0$ a lot faster than $\exp(-ct^{2})$, which contradicts what I am trying to show. Hence, I clearly have made some sort of logical error somewhere, and I can't seem to deduce where.
I am still new to asymptotics, so detailed answers would be greatly appreciated!

Take the logarithm!

This was sufficient, thank you!

The expression $$\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{t^{1/2}}\left(\frac{\lambda e}t\right)^t$$ doesn't go to zero faster than $\exp(-ct^2)$. In fact the limit as $t\to\infty$ of
$$ e^{ct^2}\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{t^{1/2}}\left(\frac{\lambda e}t\right)^t\tag 1$$  is $\infty$, as you can check by taking the logarithm of (1) [as hinted in the comment]. The key is that $t^2$ grows faster than $t\log t$.

Yes, this works, thank you!
